YouTube Analytics API returns empty data array for ageGroup viewerPercentage metrics
I’m using the YouTube Analytics API in Python to retrieve viewer percentages by age group for my YouTube channel. Here’s the code snippet:
try:
    response = (
        api_client.reports()
        .query(
            ids=f"channel=={channel_id}",
            dimensions="ageGroup",
            metrics="viewerPercentage",
            startDate=start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            endDate=end_date.isoformat(),
        )
        .execute()
    )
except Exception as e:
    logger.error(exception_message(e))
    return result

This code was working fine before, but recently the data array in the response is empty. There are no exceptions or error messages; I’m just not receiving any data.
•   What I’ve checked so far:
•   Verified that the api_client is authenticated correctly.
•   Ensured that the channel_id, start_date, and end_date are valid.
•   Confirmed that there is viewer activity during the specified date range.

Has there been any changes to the YouTube Analytics API that could cause this issue? How can I resolve this and retrieve the viewer percentages by age group again?
